# Filling an arraylist. Java

Tags: java

I have a String I split into tokens. I am trying to fill each array list with a for loop. I'm pretty close but when I test print out the array lists, it is not filling right.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class VicePresidents {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String filename = "VicePresidentAges.csv";
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner infile = new Scanner(file);

        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> ages = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        while (infile.hasNext())
        {
            
            String line = infile.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(",");
            for(int i = 0; i < tokens[0].length(); i++)
            {
                names.add(tokens[0]);
                
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < tokens[1].length(); j++)
            {
                ages.add(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]));
            }
            System.out.println(names);
            System.out.println(ages);
                        
            //Divide the line into its tokens (There should be 2 tokens per line)
            //put the tokens into their correct ArrayList
        }
        
        infile.close();

        //Go through the ages ArrayList looking for the youngest age.  
        //Hold onto the *index* where the youngest age is located in the ArrayList.
        
        
        
        //Print out the name and age for the youngest Vice President using the index
        //you just found from above
                
            
    }

}
```

My output looks like this: `[ï»¿John Adams, ï»¿John Adams, ï»¿John Adams, ï»¿John Adams, ï»¿John Adams, ï»¿John Adams]` with the ages below it like this: `[53, 53, 53, 53, 45, 45, 65, 65, 68, 68, 42, 42, 42, 42, 50, 50]`

Comment: What *should* the output be?  What is in the file?

Comment: It's a text file with Vice President's names and ages. Line 1, is "John Adams, 53".

Comment: Ah okay, I will try that. It seems I was close.

Comment: you don't need the for loops. You are adding a name multiple times instead of only once.

Comment: Now I get an error: " Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
 at VicePresidents.main(VicePresidents.java:32)"

Comment: @Eritrean is right, `tokens` should be an array with two values (the name and the age).  So you don't need to loop at all.

Comment: You shouldn't be looping over `tokens[0].length` -- that's the length of the name and doesn't matter here!

Comment: @user2740650 that is what I am confused about. If I take out the for loops, then I get " i can not be resolved to a variable ".

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Only read the content of the csv file?

Comment: These are the requirements of the assignment : Specific Requirements:
• Divide the line read from the file into its tokens
• Put the tokens from the line into their correct ArrayList
• Locate the index of the youngest age in your ages ArrayList
• Print out the name and age of the youngest Vice President from the ArrayLists
using the index located in bullet 3.

Answer (score 0):

Made some modifications to your code to get you started, try to understand and maybe improve it (extract methodes, use java.nio to read files, ...)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VicePresidents {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String filename = "VicePresidentAges.csv";
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner infile = new Scanner(file);

        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> ages = new ArrayList<>();

        while (infile.hasNext()){
            String line = infile.nextLine();
            //Divide the line into its tokens (There should be 2 tokens per line)
            String[] tokens = line.split(",");
            //put the tokens into their correct ArrayList
            names.add(tokens[0]);
            ages.add(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]));
        }        
        infile.close();
        //print both list just to check
        System.out.println(names);
        System.out.println(ages);

        //Go through the ages ArrayList looking for the youngest age.  
        //Hold onto the *index* where the youngest age is located in the ArrayList.
        int youngestIndex = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < ages.size(); i++){
            if(ages.get(i) < ages.get(youngestIndex)){
                youngestIndex = i;
            }
        }

        //Print out the name and age for the youngest Vice President using the index
        //you just found from above
        System.out.println("Youngest Vice President:");
        System.out.println("Name: " + names.get(youngestIndex) + " age: " + ages.get(youngestIndex));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, however, on my code my professor pre-coded everything up until String line = infile.nextLine();. Everything after this line except the close file is what I added. Her instructions state to not modify the code she provided.

Comment: I tried running your code and I get an error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at VicePresidents.main(VicePresidents.java:17)"

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

Comment: There was an extra bracket at the bottom and when I remove it, a whole list of errors come up. I'll need to add the errors in a new comment

Comment: Youngest Vice President:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 71 out of bounds for length 49
 at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
 at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
 at VicePresidents.main(VicePresidents.java:49)

Comment: That line `int youngest = ages.get(0);` should be `int youngest = -1;`.  It mixed up the age vs the index of the age.

Comment: Actually there's further confusion after that line -- is `youngest` supposed to be the age or the index?  Maybe rename it to `youngestIndex` for clarity.

Comment: Edited my answer and removed an error which I hadn't seen yesterday and renamed `youngest` to `youngestIndex` to avoid confusion as @user2740650 mentioned.